# Requesting to controller throws 500 Internal error when deployed to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am deploying a web service on **AZURE**. In **AZURE**, i have a **MYSQL** db and i have fed its connection string to the web.config file. Its all working fine in the local environment. But when i deploy it to **AZURE**, controller don't work. Here are the screenshots of local and remote working scenarios. Also i have traced the remote log file of that request in the screenshot.

[image: Controller's operation with the remote DB(mysql) in the local environment works about fine]
[image: Scenario in terms of remote deployment]

*Here is the log file of this error (500)*
[image]

While surfing through the internet, i came across a lot of solutions like using identity, to change authorization to none and so on. I am very confused right now as its been 2 days and i am still stuck in it. Right guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your MY SQL database is in Azure right ?

Comment: seems error in setting the connection string of your database.
Can you post your connection string (Remove sensitive information like id and password

Comment: Yup it is in azure....

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 if there would have been any problem in the connection string, then it wouldn't work locally which it does ..... i tripped checked it mate And connection string is generated by azure on the fly. So its never ever gonna be the issue

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 this is the connectionstring in web.config file both for DBcontext (which communicates with the db) and defaultconnection



<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=ap-cdbr-azure-east-c.cloudapp.net;password=;persistsecurityinfo=True;user id=;database=" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
 

 <add name="Dbcontext" connectionString="server=ap-cdbr-azure-east-c.cloudapp.net;password=;persistsecurityinfo=True;user id=;database=" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /></connectionStrings>

Comment: [Values](http://letsbuy.azurewebsites.net/api/Values)  works fine, looks like you dont have any **products**.

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 I have already added them in the tables via remote connection, if that is that problem, why is it working fine in localhost (using remote db?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem. The problem was simple. As i added the reference of mysql.data.dll in the project, i forgot to add it inside my bin folder (by checking copylocal=**true**).
After that i updated the web.config file by adding these markups in the `<system.web></system.web>`Tags.

```
<DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
```

I also enabled `custom errors="off"`, in this way i was able to get production level errors on the deployed code. `